# Compare two csv files in python and retain headers of changes

Tags: python

I'm trying to compare two csv files in python and output the differences along with the headers of each column. So far, with what I'm doing, it outputs all columns instead of just the ones with differences

```
import csv

with open('firstfile.csv', 'r') as f1:
    file1 = f1.readlines()

with open('secondfile.csv', 'r') as f2:
    file2 = f2.readlines()

with open('results.csv', 'w') as outFile:
    outFile.write(file1[0])
    for line in file2:
        if line not in file1:
            outFile.write(line)
```

Comment: I just tested this code and it works fine for me so the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: The issue is that it the out file prints all headers instead of only the ones that changed. I'm trying to print only the headers that changed. This might be bc it's evaluating lines therefore rows instead of columns (i'm not sure though)

Comment: Oh, yeah, this only outputs the rows that changed. You'd have to add a lot more code to do columns.

Comment: yeah.. not sure how to go about that. Any tips?

Comment: this isn't super clear, are the tables the same length? same number of columns? are the tableheads identical? which differences are you looking for

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarity. Solution offered below by @Ruslan Galimov works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code resolves your problem

```
import sys

with open('file1.csv', 'r') as f1:
    file1 = f1.readlines()

with open('file2.csv', 'r') as f2:
    file2 = f2.readlines()

delimiter = '\t'  # Column delimiter in you file
headers_of_first_file = file1[0].strip().split(delimiter)
headers_of_second_file = file2[0].strip().split(delimiter)

# You can remove this assert if you want to work files with different columns then you have to add some more code in next blocks
different_headers = set(headers_of_first_file).symmetric_difference(headers_of_second_file)
if different_headers:
    print('Files have difference in headers: ', different_headers)
    sys.exit(-1)

# Build map {header: [all_values]}
first_file_map = {header: [] for header in headers_of_first_file}
for row in file1[1:]:
    for index, cell in enumerate(row.strip().split(delimiter)):
        first_file_map[headers_of_first_file[index]].append(cell)

# Check by built map. Dont forget that columns may change order
result = set()
for row in file2[1:]:
    for index, cell in enumerate(row.strip().split(delimiter)):
        if cell not in first_file_map[headers_of_second_file[index]]:
            result.add(headers_of_second_file[index])

with open('results.csv', 'w') as out_file:
    out_file.write('\t'.join(result))
```

**UPD** files example:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column5 Column4
1   2   3   5   4
10  20  30  50  40

Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5
11  2   3   4   5
10  10  30  40  50
```

'\t' is delimiter

Comment: tried it out, renders the following error:
    first_file_map[headers_of_first_file[index]].append(cell)
IndexError: list index out of range

could this possibly be because there are too many columns?

Comment: Can you give an example of files?
Actually, if you have different number of columns and values in row such error may happens

Comment: Your solution worked.. the files have 100k+ rows and some data fields were missing. I used pandas to normalize the data set then ran the comparison again and it worked fine!

Comment: I was glad to help

Comment: Quick update to this.. how would I be able to handle if rows and columns are not identical?

Comment: It is your deсision. You can just write them, just print all columns with header in  `different_headers`

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

def compareList(l1,l2):
   if(len(l1)==len(l2) and len(l1)==sum([1 for i,j in zip(l1,l2) if i==j])):
      return "Equal"
   else:
      return "Non equal"

file1 = "C:/Users/Sarvesh/Downloads/a.csv"
file2 = "C:/Users/Sarvesh/Downloads/b.csv"

with open(file1, 'r') as csv1, open(file2, 'r') as csv2:  # Import CSV files
    import1 = csv1.readlines()
    import2 = csv2.readlines()

    # creating an object of csv reader
    # with the delimiter as ,
    csv_reader = csv.reader(import1, delimiter='|')
    # list to store the names of columns
    list_of_column_name1 = []
    # loop to iterate through the rows of csv
    for row in csv_reader:
        # adding the first row
        list_of_column_name1.append(row)
        # breaking the loop after the
        # first iteration itself
        break

    csv_reader = csv.reader(import2, delimiter='|')
    # list to store the names of columns
    list_of_column_name2 = []
    # loop to iterate through the rows of csv
    for row in csv_reader:
        # adding the first row
        list_of_column_name2.append(row)
        # breaking the loop after the
        # first iteration itself
        break

# printing the result
print("1List of column names : ", list_of_column_name1[0])

print("2List of column names : ", list_of_column_name2[0])

print("First comparison",compareList(list_of_column_name1,list_of_column_name2))
```